# Does `virtual: true` have any effect with an embedded schema?

Tags: elixir, ecto

The [documentation for `Ecto.Schema`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#field/3) says the following about the `:virtual` option:

> `:virtual` - When true, the field is not persisted to the database.

The [`embedded_schema/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embedded_schema/1) function says that it describes a schema kept exclusively in-memory. (i.e. It is never persisted to the DB.) Does that mean that for embedded schemas, the `:virtual` option has no effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on [`Ecto.Schema.#embedded_schema/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html?#embedded_schema/1) actually says:

> An embedded schema is *either embedded into another schema* or kept exclusively in memory. For this reason, an embedded schema does not require a source name and it does not include a metadata field.

When embedded into another schema, it acts as a snippet directly injected into the target schema, and `:virtual` fields act as usual.

When kept in memory, `:virtual` fields do still

- allow optional skip of type check by declaring type `:any`, unlike other fields
- not listed in `__schema__(:fields)`
- not support querying for type with `__schema__(:type, field)`
- not support `:autogenerate` nor `:read_after_writes` options